# Suggestion Status - a userscript to view the status of your suggested edits

Tags: script, javascript, greasemonkey, jquery, tampermonkey

**Suggestion Status** is a small userscript which displays the status of **your** suggestions using color codes; [image: accepted], [image: rejected] and yet to be reviewed. This allows you to immediately see the status of your suggestions, without first clicking the link for each suggestion.

### Screenshot

[image: Suggestion Status screenshot]

#### Development status

The current status is `alpha`: it has various known issues (which I will try to resolve as soon as possible), but its core functionality works so it's useful enough to release it to the public.

#### License

© 2012; you are free to use this userscript for any purpose, but redistribution of (parts of) the script is not allowed.

THIS USERSCRIPT IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE USERSCRIPT.

#### Known issues

1. The script only runs at `http://`<del>`stackoverflow.com`</del>`/users/<userID>/<userName>?tab=activity&sort=suggestions`

   - <del>Support for other StackExchange sites is planned to be added.</del> - ***Done***
   - Support for the `all` view of the *activities* tab is planned to be added.
2. If you are browsing to another page when you have not scrolled away from the top of the list of suggestions, the suggestion status will not appear until you scroll the page.

   - I'm currently looking into solving this.
3. The script does not auto-update

   - I'm planning to include an `@updateURL` once the script comes out of beta.
4. Reloading a full page about 9 times within a short period of time will have you temporarily [blocked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESooe.png).

   - Caching the status of suggestions that were rejected / approved is under consideration.

#### Download

Unfortunately, the script is no longer working. If you want to try to fix this, you can view the source code of the script here:

[Click here to download **Suggestion Status**.](https://gist.github.com/1k777/d5f6dac87c7a81bf0722)

#### Platform

**Suggestion Status** was developed and tested with [Scriptish](http://scriptish.org/), and it should also work with Greasemonkey, [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) and [NinjaKit](http://os0x.hatenablog.com/entry/20100612/1276330696), or any other userscript engine that supports `@require`.

#### Contact

If you have found a bug or have a suggestion, post it as a comment on this question.

#### Code

I intend to release the source code in uncompressed form once the script comes out of beta.

Comment: Your pastebin died. Maybe put it somewhere less ephemeral like Github?

Comment: @Mechanical snail Yes, sorry. It's been a while since I logged in to SO. I'll see if I can find the script and upload it.

Comment: @user2428118 Did you find that script yet?

Comment: @Cody I've found back an older (0.1.0 alpha 3) version of the script. I've modified it so it should work with the edit suggestion approval system that was in place when I last updated the script. Uploaded to some paste site: http://www.anonpaste.me/anonpaste2/index.php?511bfe43fafea31b#4MJOVfJkb0IOo4jPwj6euFPAd//zjfAX8985XFuhc/g= — I will try to find back the latest version some other time.

Comment: . @user2428118: That site seems to be dead.

Comment: @dimensio1n0 I've made a few changes and put it up again (see the link in [the post](https://stackapps.com/q/3684/12680)), but unfortunately there is a bug that causes it not to work. Anyone who wants to help me fix this is invited. (I've put the details of the error at the top of the script.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Release notes

```
Date          Version              Changes
```

```
3-10-2012     0.1.0 alpha 1        Initial version
4-10-2012     0.1.0 alpha 2        Changed regular expression @include to match
                                   all StackExchange sites
4-10-2012     0.1.0 alpha 3        Added mathoverflow.net to @include RegEx
11-10-2012    0.1.0 alpha 4        Updated regular expression to get the
                                   suggestion ID because the URL has changed
                                   from <site>/review-beta/suggested-edits/<ID>
                                   to <site>/review/suggested-edits/<ID>
9-11-2012     0.1.0 alpha 5        Added a homepage URL and a description.
```